# Trying to use a TEMPer USB Thermometer with Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, temperature

I have a $12 USB stick that records temperatures (on the device itself).

For details, see http://www.pcsensor.com/usb-thermometers/gold-temper.html

I downloaded its software, **and it works fine in Windows** - currently Win-10 Insider Preview 17945 or whatever the latest "FAST" Win-10 is... (Now, I'm currently in Linux)

When I boot into Ubuntu 17.10, and compile the supplied software (makefile, C-program etc) I get

```
$ temper232    
/dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
```

An `lsusb` shows

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c45:7401 Microdia TEMPer Temperature Sensor
```

The C program has a line:

```
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

---

```
$ dmesg | grep -i temper    shows     
[    2.490091] usb 2-5.4: Product: TEMPerV1.4
[    2.493187] input: RDing TEMPerV1.4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-5/2-5.4/2-5.4:1.0/0003:0C45:7401.0003/input/input5     
[    2.553603] hid-generic 0003:0C45:7401.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [RDing TEMPerV1.4] on usb-0000:00:13.2-5.4/input0     
[    2.555527] hid-generic 0003:0C45:7401.0004: hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [RDing TEMPerV1.4] on usb-0000:00:13.2-5.4/input1
```

So where can I go from here? It seems to be some USB / Serial port thing. I haven't used serial ports since floppy disks on Win 3.1!

There is a lot of info on the internet on this device, but most of it involves Python, Github, Raspberry-PI LAMPs (which I also have), PERL (gads!), and something called a "mock", which I never heard of before! Must read-up on it!

I just want the basic device to respond with a temperature, at least in a terminal!

More info can be supplied! Just ask!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on CentOS but it should be the same on Ubuntu.

First install with `pip install temperusb` (if this fails try `pip2 install temperusb` to explicitly request the usage of python2 pip)

Then you just run `temper-poll` and it will prints the current reading.

Comment: Thanx!  But I've pretty well given up on this USB device. Why?
Because its USB power generates heat IN THE DEVICE. 
I made several measurements and the device always- ALWAYS - shows a few degrees above the ambient temperature. And this depends on whether it is +20C or -15C. And whether a wind is blowing (cools the device).
It's fine for rough measurement (freezing pipes or winecellar heating up) but no good for a detailed temperature log.

Comment: ADDENDUM - I found many complaints about this device- how it would heat up insanely (250C etc), and sometimes folks offered how to "re-calibrate" its high temperature. 
Note: its temperature was ALWAY "high", never "low". Now do you understand why?
Heck it is still good for a $11 device.

Comment: @aqk I was about ready to use it for emergency shutdown of my server in case of over heating. In the first 24 hours of tests it seems ok but your info is troubling. Maybe it's over heating only if you're polling too frequently or I was just lucky. Have you found a replacement that is not ten times more expensive?

Comment: I'm sure it will work fine for your purpose.
I am trying to set up a simple "weather station", and I'd like the temp to be as accurate as possible. Perhaps I can glue the device to a larger piece of metal, that will act as a heat sink, and always show the ambient temp. I just have to keep the apparatus out of the Sun!      
No, I havent yet found one that insn't 10x as expensive! LOL ;-)

Comment: PS- Thanx for the "Wake-up" question! I haven't looked at this project for a few months. Time to resume!  And I just came up with the wonderful Heat-Sink idea while reading your comment!  PS#2 My polling is 1 min. Maybe I'll chg it to 5 minutes.

Comment: The heat-sink seems like a great Idea (small volume large air-conducting surface) but for a weather station maybe an arduino + some good IC (like the SHT15) would be a better solution. Anyway if you try my answer and it works for you too, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: The comments about internal heat production may be right for a Temper-1F, but I have some of the older Temper-1 (without F), which have a 50 cm lead between the USB plug + electronics and the actual sensor. The results I get seem pretty much correct.

Comment: @ndemou Rehash- 3+ years later.     The Temper does develop heat and of course this affects its reading. I dropped this project, but have now resumed it (Aug,2021) due to global warming/ climate change, etc.     
 Why linux?  Because I have an old ASUS eee machine with 2GB that still runs.  I'll add it to my home network (with Lubuntu presumably) and get this Temper and its big steel tile heat-exchanger on the end of a 10M USB cable  outside my house (on N side naturally) to start recording our civilisations demise due to global warming!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Given the device states: "(Note: Our software just support windows OS .)", I'm not 100% sure this will work but should be worth a try.

Try the script here: [command to determine ports of a device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0#144735) - to find the correct device path for your temperature sensor.

Then comple the C program again, but add `MODEMDEVICE=/path/to/device/` from the script results in the command line when you compile.  According to [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html), this should override the flag in the program source.

Comment: Sorry- got involved with other projects.       recompiled the C pgm with changes but problem remains.        Seems the li'l Temper guy isn't too friendly towards Linux.      Will forward more details soon.

Answer (score 0):

There's a python library that supports some of the devices:

https://github.com/urwen/temper

I have a USB thermometer that isn't supported by that library.

I tried to reverse engineer the HID-based protocol, but since the last time I tried this (2012?) computers now have so many more USB devices that I couldn't even isolate the thing to do reliable packet capture.

Instead, the model I have has a "TXT" button on it that switches the device over to be a keyboard and periodically types the temperature.

It registers itself as `/dev/input/by-id/usb-413d_2107-event-kbd` when in "TXT" mode, and so I was able to use `sudo evtest --grab /dev/input/by-id/usb-413d_2107-event-kbd` to capture its input, and then some massaging to convert the keystrokes into a series of Celsius temperature values.

Here's my script that grabs the USB device (when it's in "TXT" mode) and translates the keystrokes into temperature values:

```
#!/bin/sh

device_path='/dev/input/by-id/usb-413d_2107-event-kbd'

sed_script='s/^Event:.*(EV_KEY), code \([0-9]\+\)\s.*\(KEY_\w\+\).*, value 1$/\2/p'


sudo evtest --grab "$device_path" | \
        sed --unbuffered --silent "$sed_script" | \
        while read key; do
                case "$key" in
                        KEY_[0-9]) printf '%s' "${key#KEY_}" ;;
                        KEY_DOT) printf '.' ;;
                        KEY_ENTER) printf '\n' ;;
                        *) printf 'X'
                esac
        done | \
        sed --unbuffered 's/X.*//; /^$/d' | \
        while read temp; do echo "$temp"; echo "$(date +%s) $temp" >>celsius.log; done
```

Your mileage may vary.